# How to fix WebView "blocking pop up windows"?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use WebView to open our project app , and when we tape to 
take photo with android device the popup windows dont appear .
however when i access the app with browser the popup appear and we can select camera .
what and where do I need to update the code ?

//main Activity //

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public WebView webView ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://projectapp.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());




}
```

// Manifest //

```
package="com.rolloutapp.projectapp.simpleapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.rolloutapp.projectapp.simpleapp.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

ability to take pictures with android device with WebView

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this code in your `onCreate()`:

```py
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: iv got issue with "webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
" when i hover it it says "can not resolve method setPluginsEnabled´(boolean)"

Comment: error:error: non-static method getSettings() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Oh sorry, that was Uppercase (WebView) @ziouaniidir